# Change the device ID on an Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there a way to change the IMEI that will be returned by the emulator's `TelephonyManager`?  Also, is there a way to change the ID returned by `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID`?

I use these IDs to distinguish my users from one another when storing their data on the server side.  It would be nice if my QA team could change these IDs so that they are not all using the same set of user data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [this page](http://codepainters.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/android-imei-number-and-the-emulator/) outlines a method that involves manually modifying the emaultor.exe file. It seems pretty straightforward, though you'd have to create a separate emulator for each QA team member.

Comment: Instead of providing a link to the solution, please describe the answer

Comment: See my post below for a short script example of modifying the emulator binary, same technique as in the article.

Answer (score 8):

As far as `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` goes, this should do the trick:

`adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "UPDATE secure SET value='newid' WHERE name='android_id'`"

Where `newid` is usually the 16 hex digit code (i.e. don't append "Android_" to it).
I only tried this on the emulator. I imagine a real phone would need to be rooted first.

Comment: I think this answer describes the easiest way to actually _change_ the value. You still need a way _refresh_ the Android runtime cache, though. From the top of my head, the only way I can think of to do that is to restart the emulator which is a bit inconvenient from a timing perspective :-(

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: There is no more database there  ```adb shell ls /data/data/com.android.providers.settings -la
total 24
drwx------   4 system system 4096 2018-12-08 21:09 .
drwxrwx--x 116 system system 8192 2018-12-21 21:46 ..
drwxrws--x   2 system system 4096 2018-12-08 21:09 cache
drwxrws--x   2 system system 4096 2018-12-08 21:09 code_cache```

Answer (score 4):

answer of zyc zyc is the best one until android 7.1.1 (25). From android 8 rules of android_id has changed as described in the official developer documentation: 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html

> In O, Android ID (Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID or SSAID) has a different value for each app and each user on the device. Developers requiring a device-scoped identifier, should instead use a resettable identifier, such as Advertising ID, giving users more control. Advertising ID also provides a user-facing setting to limit ad tracking.
>   Additionally in Android O:
>   The ANDROID_ID value won't change on package uninstall/reinstall, as long as the package name and signing key are the same. Apps can rely on this value to maintain state across reinstalls.
>   If an app was installed on a device running an earlier version of Android, the Android ID remains the same when the device is updated to Android O, unless the app is uninstalled and reinstalled.
>   The Android ID value only changes if the device is factory reset or if the signing key rotates between uninstall and reinstall events.
>   This change is only required for device manufacturers shipping with Google Play services and Advertising ID. Other device manufacturers may provide an alternative resettable ID or continue to provide ANDROID ID.

Answer (score 2):

query android_id use this command in adb shell:

> settings get secure android_id

change android_id use this command in adb shell:

> settings put secure android_id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: will these new values persist between runs?

Answer (score 1):

Additional to @zyc-zyc answer

`settings get secure android_id`

`settings put secure android_id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Which doesn't work at least on Android P (28) I tried to update via sql

`adb shell content delete --uri content://settings/secure --where "name=\'android_id\'"`

`adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/secure --bind name:s:android_id --bind value:s:XYXYXYX`

check the result:

`adb shell content query --uri content://settings/secure --where "name=\'android_id\'"`

> Row: 0 _id=186, name=android_id, value=XYXYXYX

`adb shell settings get secure android_id`

> XYXYXYX

Update works, but all solutions have **no affect in device** when I read value

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

Comment: You are correct. it updates the value but when trying via code its not changing.

Comment: did you find any work around for this? how can we get this ANDROID_ID which we set via adb command above

Comment: No, this topic becomes to be obsolete for me

Comment: I found it. I was trying the commands on emulator with Android 13 which looks not rooted by default. but when I tried the same commands using Android Naugat it worked also it working with Code too (worked on rooted device)

Answer (score 1):

In case you still need to change the IMEI, and need to do it from a script:

```
EMU=$ANDROID_BASE/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
p=$$ # Something unique enough
perl -e '
  $imei=substr("'$p'"."0"x15,0,15); $/=undef;
  open IN, "'$EMU'" or die "$!"; $b=<IN>; close IN;
  $b=~s/(\+CGSN.)0{15}/${1}$imei/;
  open OUT, ">'$EMU'-imei" or die "$!"; print OUT $b ; close OUT
'
```

then move your original qemu-system-x86_64 binary so you can rename the new -imei one into its place. Use `CIMI` in the `$b=~` line instead of `CGSN` to change the IMSI (copy and adapt the `$b=~` line if you need both).

Obviously you'll need a different path for Mac/Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Since Oreo, android id is unique per user per package and stored in:

`/data/system/users/(user_id)/settings_ssaid.xml`

There's even an [open-source project on github](https://github.com/CoNsTaRs/oreo_device_id_changer) with prebuilt binaries that can query and modify the id for you. You will need root access, however, that should be not an issue on emulators.

Changes seem to take effect only after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Wipe Data]

Hi, I just wipe the data of the emulator. It's resolved.
But mean your "new" device.